# Run the method as soon as the page becomes visible

Tags: c#, maui

I have a content page that is just a waiting screen that shows the results of the execution of some processes in real time. I need to run the method that start those proccesses as soon as the page becomes visible.

I tried the following options but they didn't help: run it from costructor, from overrided OnAppearing() method, on Loaded event.

Using Loaded event:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += LongProcess;
    }

    void LongProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < 10) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            counter++;
            label.Text = counter.ToString();
        }
    }

}


<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testlongprocces.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="0"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Interesting. Why overridden OnAppearing did not work for you? Can you show me how did that method look like?

Comment: Because I did not use that correctly, to be honest I am not C# developer at all, so sometimes I get some obvious mistakes. Thanks yall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guy who suggested right solution disappeared, the working code:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Appearing += OnPageAppearing;
}

private async void OnPageAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RunProceses();
}

private async Task RunProceses()
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking your main thread. Make LongProcess method async and use `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`

```
    async void LongProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < 10)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            counter++;
            label.Content = counter.ToString();
        }
    }
```